# New room indoor staggered wall: I did not check if wall studs were on the same plane. How bad will drywalling be?

Tags: framing, studs

[image]

Hello! I just learned about the concept of plumb studs and having studs on the same plane.

I have not had the experience of adding drywall or any wallboard yet, but I tackled this project anyway.

Any recommendations moving forward? Can I still make this wall work despite the possibility of studs not being fully plumbed or completely on the same plane?

Will using tongue and groove boards instead of drywall be any better?

Some info about the wall: this is a 10 feet staggered wall where every 8 inches, there is a new stud, but every stud is pushed to either side of the bottom plate. My understanding is this should help with sound proofing.

Comment: If every second stud is in the same plane, a long straight edge does not show difference, then it should be okay.  The wall not being plumb might bug you if it is out enough.  Perfect plumb is a nice idea seldom obtained, but should be within 1/8 to 1/4 inch.

Answer (score 2):

Purchase 12 foot sheets of drywall.

Hang them horizontally and you will only have one horizontal seam.

The studs being 16 inches apart on each plane will be fine.

This actually looks like a very easy drywall job.

Of course install whatever insulation in the wall prior.

Answer (score 1):

If this really every other stud offset by the same amount, thank them -- that's a bit more effort to build, but gives better insulation against both noise and heat flow. You wallboard by driving screws only into the studs on that side of the wall. This is more than enough to support it.

(Studs which are fastened to wallboard on both sides transmit vibration from one to the other.)

Comment: I get potential noise, but why are we concerned about heat flow here?

Comment: You may not be. I'm just pointing out the potential advantages since I have no idea what that room will be used for.

Comment: I mean, unless it's gonna be some kind of refrigeration room, or a sauna, or maybe some kind of reptile room...

Comment: Some of us do like to keep different rooms at different temperatures. Public space vs. bedroom vs office...